# Extracting additional Content python requests

Tags: python, web-scraping, python-requests, scraper

I am looking to extract generated content from a web page.

I am using the library requests in python 3 to return the page as below

```
 import requests 
 url = "https://app.updateimpact.com/treeof/org.json4s/json4s- 
  native_2.11/3.5.2"

 html_doc = requests.get(url)
 print(html_doc.text)
```

The retrieve text seems to be just padding though. What tools should I be looking at to drill into the content and extract the info there ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Javascript needs to run on the page to provide much of the content. Using a method like selenium will allow this to run. Note that an additional wait condition is needed to ensure certain content is loaded. You can then use selenium syntax to extract info or dump the html from page_source into BeautifulSoup.

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait 
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs

d = webdriver.Chrome()
d.get('https://app.updateimpact.com/treeof/org.json4s/json4s-native_2.11/3.5.2')
dependencies = WebDriverWait(d, 5).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR , '.stats-list')))
print(dependencies)
soup = bs(d.page_source, 'lxml')
print(soup.select_one('#tree').text) # example
```

Comment: Interesting. There must be some sort of cookie that contains a timer because the url works for awhile

Comment: I just noticed that there is an error in your URL , there should be no gap between json4s- || native      'https://app.updateimpact.com/treeof/org.json4s/json4s-native_2.11/3.5.2'

Comment: That was careless of me! Thanks. Lemme have another look.

Comment: that looks to be on point. Although I am having issues running it as the path to my Chrome driver is throwing errors. I am pointing to its location in the python site-package but will need to google it more to see why it no works. Will mark solution as answer as soon as I can confirm it. :)

Comment: No worries. Anything else I can help with let me know.

Comment: thats on point. Can you recommend a good source for getting documentation on this ? I want to look into a) parsing out the return text so that it is not one string and b) how to open up some of the child clicks so I can dig into the root of the returned tree type

Comment: https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/#    and https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#

Answer (score 0):

If the content is html, you could look into:

- https://docs.python.org/3/library/html.parser.html
- https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/

If it's json, you would use:

- https://docs.python.org/3/library/json.html